# How to start over again in Java?

Tags: java

I have this following program  and I want to have a loop that asks the user if he wants to play again and if he wants the program or the play starts over again.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Crapl {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double budget;
        int toGo = 1;
        while (toGo == 1) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("What is your budget");
            budget = input.nextDouble();
            play(budget);
        }
    }
    // rool method

    public static int roll() {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int dice1, dice2;

        dice1 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dice2 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.printf("\tYou rolled %d+%d=%d\t", dice1, dice2, dice1 + dice2);
        return dice1 + dice2;
    }

    public static void play(double budget) {
        int con, gamePoint, game;
        int toGo = 1;
        con = 0;   //game will continue
        double bet, budget2, userCredit = 0;
        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
        gamePoint = 0;
        budget2 = budget;

        System.out.printf("You have $%.2f available balance, how much you want to bet:\n", budget);
        bet = get.nextDouble();

        while (bet > budget) {
            System.out.printf("You ONLY have $%.2f available balance, how much you want to bet:\n", budget);
            bet = get.nextDouble();
        }

        if (budget == 0.00) {
            System.out.printf("you have $%.2f balance , so you cant play anymore ", budget);
        }

        budget = budget - bet;//withdraw amount from budget
        game = roll(); //play game

        switch (game) {
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 12:
                con = -1; //game lost
                System.out.printf("Sory you have lost the game. Your remaining balance is $%.2f\n", budget);
                break;
            case 7:
            case 11:
                con = 1;
                System.out.printf("You won the game. Your remaining balance is $%.2f\n", budget + 2 * bet);
                break;
            default:
                con = 0;
                gamePoint = game;
                System.out.printf("Game point is %d\n", gamePoint);
        }

        while (con == 0) {
            System.out.printf("\nYou have $%.2f available balance, how much you want to bet:\n", budget);
            bet = get.nextDouble(); //one loop
            while (bet > budget) {
                System.out.printf("You ONLY have $%.2f available balance, how much you want to bet:\n", budget);
                bet = get.nextDouble();
            }

            budget -= bet; //withdraw the bet from budget
            userCredit += bet; //keep adding total bet into userCredit.
            game = roll();

            if (game == 7) {
                con = -1;
                System.out.printf("\nSory you have lost the game. Your remaining balance is $%.2f\n", budget);
            } else if (game == gamePoint) {
                con = 1;
                budget2 += userCredit;
                System.out.printf("\nYou have won the game. Your remaining balance is $%.2f\n", budget2);

                System.out.printf("Would you like to play again?\n");
                System.out.printf("If yes enter 1 0 otherwise\n");
                toGo = get.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First off, you're doing everything statically. Place all of your variables and such in an object. In your main method, instantiate the object within a do while loop.

At the end of the loop, ask if the player wants to replay, then loop based on the answer. At that point, you can re-initialize the object if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Add a prompt asking the user if they want to play again at the end of your loop in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{


  double budget;
  int toGo=1;
  while(toGo==1)
  {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your budget");
    budget=input.nextDouble();

    /* budget = 0 is not allowed */
    while (budget <= 0)
    {
       System.out.print("What is your budget");
       budget=input.nextDouble();
    }

    play(budget);

    System.out.println("Do you want to play again?")
    toGo = input.nextInt();
  } 

}
```

Comment: but, in this case the user can enter 0 as a budget and I do not want to allow the user to do that

Comment: See my edit. It's just a different loop to stop allowing 0 as a budget.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to put everything you want that is to be repeated in a while loop. The condition for this while loop will be a `boolean` variable that is set to `true` if the player wants to play again and `false` otherwise.

When the user enters in a 1, you would set the `boolean` variable to true.